# What kind of salvage do Rogue Drones drop (if any)?

Tags: eve-online

Just wondering if it's worth to salvage missions like Rogue Drone Harassment and similar ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rogue Drones have all Salvage Parts in their [loot table](http://games.chruker.dk/eve_online/salvaging.php), except Damaged Artificial Neural Network. Therefore it is worth salvaging.